# Please help understand proof of small span theorem in multivariable calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum, partitions-for-integration

The proof of small span theorem (given in Apostol Volume 2) is as follows:

[image]

**Please (if possible) give a detailed proof of this theorem including all information in the above proof**

$\mathrm{off}$ is to be read as "of $f$"

Comment: Sorry..... there are certain misprints in this book... "off" is to be replaced with "of $f$"

Comment: @AlvinLepik I think it is mistype for  'of $f$'.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Makes the text difficult to read.

Comment: Never post unsearchable pictures.  Instead typeset in *MathJax*.  And what have you tried?

Comment: I'd say the argument is quite straightforward, so please specify which points you have problems with. There is nothing significant for you to gain if someone re-typed this proof as an answer.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: OK

Comment: ... we obtain an infinite set of subintervals $I ^ {(1)}, I ^ {(2)},....$ in each of which the span of $f$ is at least $\epsilon_0$..... There may be "more than one" infinite sets and "more than one" $t$... If this is so, which one shall we choose?

Comment: We can come up with "more than one" infinite sets each having its corresponding $t$. If this is so, which one shall we choose?

Comment: Can any one explain a bit elaborately?

Comment: @lorilori It's not a question of which set of intervals to pick, but why we can pick it. Once we have one such set, a contradiction follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass this argument in $\mathbb R$. In $\mathbb R^n$ the interval is to be thought of as
$$[a,b] = \{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b \mid 0\leq \lambda\leq 1 \}. $$
The central part to the argument concerns that infinite set of subintervals.

Assuming, for a contradiction, the theorem is false, after every bisection, the finite set of subintervals (as a partition) does not satisfy the condition for $f$. More precisely, every finite partition contains at least one subinterval whose span of $f$ is at least $\varepsilon _0$.

Start generating finite partitions by bisection. Firstly $[a,b] = [a,x_1]\cup [x_1,b]$. By hypothesis, at least one of them has span of $f$ at least $\varepsilon _0$. Suppose it's $[a,x_1]$. Bisect again by $[a,x_1] = [a,x_2]\cup [x_2,x_1]$ and pick a subinterval whose span of $f$ is at least $\varepsilon _0$. Proceed analogously and obtain an infinite set of subintervals $I_k$, where $I_{k+1}\subseteq I_k$ for every $k\in\mathbb N$.

Put $t := \sup  \left\{ \min\limits_{u\in I_k} u \mid k\in\mathbb N \right\}$. Now use continuity of $f$ at $t$ and the fact that the subintervals $I_k$ get smaller.

---

For the sake of clarity, I understand span of $f$ of some interval $I$ to be the diameter of its image under $f$ i.e $\mathrm{span}_f(I) := \sup \{\|f(x)-f(y)\| \mid x,y\in I\} = \mathrm{diam}(f(I))$. I've never heard it being called the span, though.

Comment: If we have not defined the set $I_k$, how can $$t=\sup  \left\{ \min\limits_{u\in I_k} u \mid k\in\mathbb N \right\}$$ be meaningful?

Comment: Proceed analogously and obtain an infinite set of subintervals $I_k$.... We can not obtain an infinite set of subintervals. After reaching any finite step, there are several variations to follow. How can we say "proceed analogously (through any variation) and obtain an infinite set"?

Comment: @lorilori We can't predict which half the consecutive bisection has a large span of $f$, so it would notationally be a nightmare. Instead, we generate finite partitions and at every step we pick an appropriate subinterval, whose existence is guaranteed by hypothesis.